# What are the changes in the battle system from FF13 to FF13-2(if any)?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

So far in FF13-2, the battle system seems the same as the one used in FF13. Are there any differences between the two systems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several differences, some major, some minor:

- No Eidolons
- Several paradigm role abilities have been removed or consolidated
- Paradigm shifts are much faster and do not have heavy animations involved in them
- Party AI within each paradigm can be tuned to focus on one enemy or area-of-effect attacks
- Deterministic pre-emptive strikes via the Mog Clock: you decide how to engage most non-boss battles
- Incorporation of cinematic action sequences (read: quick-time events)
- No permanent third party member: replaced with a "paradigm pack" of monsters, which allows one of three monsters to be switched out mid-battle depending on your paradigm deck
- Monsters have "feral link" abilities (read: limit breaks)